# asp mvc page load forever

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Hi guys im new in asp mvc 
my question is that i created model

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyDemo.Models
{
    public class Teachers
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LASTNAME { get; set; }
    }
}
```

then base on this model created controller by using scaffolding that created this for me

```
u

sing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyDemo.Models;

namespace MyDemo.Controllers
{
    public class TeachersController : Controller
    {
        private MyDemoContext db = new MyDemoContext();

        // GET: Teachers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Teachers.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Teachers/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Teachers teachers = db.Teachers.Find(id);
            if (teachers == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(teachers);
        }

        // GET: Teachers/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Teachers/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,NAME,LASTNAME")] Teachers teachers)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Teachers.Add(teachers);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(teachers);
        }

        // GET: Teachers/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Teachers teachers = db.Teachers.Find(id);
            if (teachers == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(teachers);
        }

        // POST: Teachers/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,NAME,LASTNAME")] Teachers teachers)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(teachers).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(teachers);
        }

        // GET: Teachers/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Teachers teachers = db.Teachers.Find(id);
            if (teachers == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(teachers);
        }

        // POST: Teachers/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Teachers teachers = db.Teachers.Find(id);
            db.Teachers.Remove(teachers);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

and then created views (index,create,delete,insert) with that controllers
the problem is when i navigate to localhost/Teachers/Index . the page load forever and nothing to show . and when manually create another controller base on another model it was worked fine. where is the problem ???

Comment: Show your view too and viewmodel if applicable

Comment: Does db.Teachers.ToList() return anything, or do you get already a timeout there ?

Comment: what do you mean by viewmodel . as i say im new in asp mvc . what i know about mvc in model , view , controller

Answer (score 0):

I think check your connection string. You can put breakpoint in index action method of TeachersController and see that you are getting the teacherlist. Most probably the error will be of connection to database. You can try by changing

```
return View(db.Teachers.ToList()); to just return View();
```

and on view just write plain html.

Comment: i have two connection string . is it normal

Comment: <add name="TeacherContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=TeacherContext-20170204205934; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|TeacherContext-20170204205934.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: <add name="MyDemoContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=MyDemoContext-20170208133257; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDemoContext-20170208133257.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: They look normal and seem to be generated by MVC. You should put a breakpoint in the "Index"-Method (Action) of "TeachersController" (Controller) and debug db.Teachers and tell us if it does have any values or exceptions

Comment: The database are different for both the connection string you can try by creating the object of TeacherContext so you can change the code in TeachersController class from   "private MyDemoContext db = new MyDemoContext();" to "private TeacherContext db=new TeacherContext();"